# How to use shared variable in labview for communicating strings?

Tags: variables, shared, labview

i have created two projects,one as master and one as slave to read a string from slave to master in labview using DSC module.Master is showing error in opening connection to shared varibles.Ihave tried every known options to debug it.Can ny1 help by providing block dig or giving some tips for same??
i would really appreciate ny help.

Answer (score 1):

What error is your Master showing?

If you would like an example, NI provides one with LabVIEW that might be helpful. Go to the Help menu, then click "Find Examples..." to open the Example Finder. Browse according to task to Networking >> Shared Variable >> Shared Variable.lvproj.